# Getting an empty graph even though I add a node in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to add a node into an empty graph with an attribute, which I need to be an integer. However, it doesn't seem to add it because when I print(G) it gives me None

Here is my code:

```
def heirarchy_graph(n,e,l):
'''
n is number of nodes in graph,
e is the Expansion Rate. This is the number of people on each level
   If n/e has a remainder then the last level has that many
   people in it.
l is the Level connection. It is the probability that a person is connected to someone
  within the level they belong to.
'''
G = nx.Graph()
G.name="heirarchy_graph(%s,%s,%s)"%(n,e,l)

r = (n-1)%e
s = (n-r-1)/e
h = s + 1
G = empty_graph(n=0)

G = G.add_node(0, level=int(0))
print(G)
for i in range(s):
    list = range(1,(e+1))
    A = nx.Graph()
    #for item in list:
        #create e nodes with attribute level='i'
    A.add_nodes_from(list,level=int(i))

    # add edges between nodes with probability l
    names = A.nodes()

    for name in names:
        B = non_neighbors(A,name)
        for u in B:
            q = random.uniform(0,1)
            if q <= l:
                A.add_edge(u,name)
    return A
    print(A)
    G = nx.disjoint_union(G,A)


if r != 0: 
    h = s+1
    list = range(1,(r+1))
    A = nx.Graph()
    #create e nodes with attribute level='i'
    A.add_nodes_from(list,level=int(h))
    # add edges between nodes with probability l
    names = A.nodes()
    for name in names:
        B = non_neighbors(A,name)
        for u in B:
            q = random.uniform(0,1)
            if q <= l:
                A.add_edge(u,name)
    return A

    G = nx.disjoint_union(G,A)

return G
```

The result of the print(G) is None

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you've got other problems as well:  You've got `return A` .  The moment your function gets to this line, it will return `A` to whatever called it and stop any more calculations in this function.  So it will only execute the first time through the first loop.  It won't get any further than that.

Comment: Another issue: I assume this is just a temporary thing, but right now you add edges with probability 1.  So you could skip the random number generation and testing if you simply add the edges all the time.

Comment: If later you're going to add edges with some smaller probability, you should take a look at `nx.fast_gnp_random_graph`

Comment: Thank you, that actually solved another problem I had after I got the graph to add the node!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `add_node` is stateful and modifies the graph `G` directly.
Because `add_node` does not return anything, when you try to assign to `G`, `G` is `None`.

Try:

```
G.add_node(0, level=int(0))
```